# List of all (also optional) query parameters in java rest web service

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I want to have all query parameters in a list. As well those that were **not** used in the get method.
My method:

```
@GET
@Produces({"text/csv"})
@Path("/somesearch/")
public Response method1(
        @DefaultValue("0") @QueryParam("param1") float param1,
        @DefaultValue("0") @QueryParam("param2") float param2,
        // further optional parameters... not only floats){
    ArrayList<Object> parameters = new ArrayList<Object>();
    parameters.add(param1);
    parameters.add(param2);
    // add further query parameters
    // do something ...
 }
```

so is there a possibility to obtain all the parameters (even those not set in the GET request) in a list?
I can't use the @context uriInfo with its getQueryParameters() method because it lists the parameters used in the url

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the @DefaultValue annotation, but if I had to do it I would have done it something like this..

```
 @GET
    @Produces({"text/csv"})
    @Path("/somesearch/")
    public Response method1(@Context UriInfo uriInfo){
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> multiParameters = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
       // multiParameters contains all the parameters in key-value pairing format
     }
```

Comment: This does not work. As I said uriInfo.getQueryParameters() returns only a list with set parameters.
E. g.
URL : http://example.com/somesearch?param1=10

In this case only param1 would be in the list returned by  uriInfo.getQueryParameters() by param 2 is still missing

Comment: okay got your point...May I know what is the issue with what you are trying...means are u getting any error or the parameters list is not getting populated?

Comment: The issue is that I want loop through all query parameters, even if not set they have a default value. I was asking if there is a possibility to obtain a complete list of those query parameters instead of creating an own list and adding every entry with a new line.